# Searching Azure Log Analytics SigninLogs shows no data

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

Within the Azure Logs *Configure signal logic* blade, I'm trying to create an email alert whenever a particular user logs into Azure.

Following [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-emergency-access#create-an-alert-rule), the following logic should return the recent logins, but it is showing nothing despite that user *definitely* logging in multiple times today:

```
SigninLogs
| project UserId
| where UserId == "f1cd9e01-[removed]-c9cd45e984da"
```

The UserId value being used is the Object Id from their respective Azure AD user page, so it's definitely correct.

If I remove the `| where` clause entirely then still no data is returned.

Can anybody suggest any reason why this wouldn't show any data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to query Azure AD sign-in logs in  Azure Log Analytics, we should send the logs to Azure Log Analytics at first. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/howto-integrate-activity-logs-with-log-analytics) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-emergency-access#prerequisites).

Besides, please note that if you want to send Azure AD sign-in logs to Azure Log Analytics, you should have  Azure AD Premium P1 or P2 license.

for example

1. Sign in to the Azure portal.
2. Select **Azure Active Directory** > **Diagnostic settings** -> Add diagnostic setting. You can also select **Export Settings** from the **Audit Logs** or **Sign-ins** page to get to the diagnostic settings configuration page.
3. In the **Diagnostic settings** menu, select the **Send to Log Analytics workspace** check box, and then select Configure.
4. Select the Log Analytics workspace you want to send the logs to, or create a new workspace in the provided dialog box.
5. Do either or both of the following:

   - To send audit logs to the Log Analytics workspace, select the **AuditLogs** check box.
   - To send sign-in logs to the Log Analytics workspace, select the **SignInLogs** check box.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Jim.  The subscription level was the problem.  Not sure why this isn't part of the lower packages given how much better security it provides...? (end rant)